# Font Awesome accessibility issue. Use <em> tags instead of <i>

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, wcag2.0

I am testing my HTML code markup compliance with accessibility standards: http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php. The following is an error I get:

> Repair: Replace your i elements with em or strong.

```
<i class="fa fa-search" title="Search"></i> <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
```

I went through the official Font Awesome docs on the accessibility (https://cdn.fontawesome.com/help#qa-autoa11y), and didn't find any mention of that I need to use different tags for icons. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Since there is no readable text involved the `i` can safely be used.

Comment: ...but if you are *really* concerned...use a `span` instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks. I think I will replace them with spans just in case.

Comment: Font Awesome's [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use): _Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements and we recommend sticking with a consistent HTML element to reference them by in your project. We like the_ `<i>` _tag for brevity and for the fact that most folks are using_ `<em></em>` _for emphasized/italicized semantic text these days. If that’s not your cup of tea, using a_ `<span>` _is more semantically correct._

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As a general guideline, you should use `em` for emphasis instead of `i` for italic text because italic text is normally used only to imply emphasis.

In this case, you are using `i` for *icon*, which is nonsense (and confusing your accessibility checking tool). Use a `span` instead. That doesn't come loaded with any inappropriate semantics.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: @sdvnskv it seems this conventional wisdom is no longer true. "In earlier versions of the HTML specification, the <i> element was merely a presentational element used to display text in italics, much like the <b> element was used to display text in bold letters. This is no longer true, as these tags now define semantics rather than typographic appearance." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Comment: @JeromyFrench — The semantics given to `i` elements are still nonsense for this use case.

Answer (score 8):

On a strict and semantic HTML, font icons have to be tagged with `span`s:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa fa-camera-retro"></span>
```

[Font Awesome examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) appears with `<i>` (italic tags) because of abbreviation coding. Just it.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a 2016 answer... you may use `aria-hidden="true"` on your tag, like this: `<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>`, tho.

That's explained on:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/html/RSPEC-1100 and https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-hidden%3Dtrue_on_an_icon_font_that_AT_should_ignore

Comment: Even though those specifications exist, validators like achecker.ca dont seem to comply with them. Guess the best way is to go with <span> elements

Comment: The biggest downfall of `aria-hidden="true"` is that it does not work well with dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

> The `<em>` element represents stress emphasis of its contents.

If you’re not stressing emphasis on a particular word, then you should use `<i>`.

> The `<i>` element is more appropriately used for presentation purpose.

You could use `<i>` to mark up a quotation – not to add emphasis to the entire phrase or paragraph, but to differentiate it or offset it from the main text.

http://www.silkstream.net/blog/2016/02/b-vs-strong-i-vs-em-whats-the-difference.html

In your instance, it may suggest using `<em>` because some specialized accessibility software's may handle them with more emphasis.

Comment: *You could use `<i>` to mark up a quotation* — You shouldn't though. We have [the `<q>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element).